# Error in Page in modo edition

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, chrome

Currently I have a problem when try edit a page.

When edit a webpart and in property window of webpart I click on the button:

[image]

but does not open the modal window, and displays the following error:

[image]

This only happens in Google Chrome.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: SharePoint 2013

Comment: What kind of webpart is it?

Comment: data view form web part -  XSLT